# Haskell - Takes a list of floats and returns a list of chars

Tags: haskell

I am wondering to create a Haskell function to take a list of floats and returns a list of chars that represent the letter grades based off the original scores.
I can complete this requirement without list:

```
 convertRawsToLetters :: (RealFloat score) => score -> Char
 convertRawsToLetters score
    | score > 90 = 'A'
    | score <= 90 && score > 80 = 'B'
```

How can I use condition in list?

Comment: Do you know the function `map`?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function that converts ONE float to a Char, as you've done here:

```
convertRawsToLetters :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Char
convertRawsToLetters s | s > 90    = 'A'
                       | s > 80    = 'B'
                       | s > 70    = 'C'
                       | otherwise = 'F'
```

(note that I don't have to run both inequalities here since the guards are evaluated in order)

Then you map that over the list of floats. `map` has type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

so its first argument is a function from `a -> b` (`Float -> Char`, in this case), its second argument is a list of `a`s (`Float`s), and it returns a list of `b`s (`Char`s).

```
listOfChars :: [Char]
listOfChars = map convertRawsToLetters listOfFloats
```